# Why are the headers for an Azure Function empty?

Tags: javascript, azure

I have a very simple function:

```
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");

async function download(request, context) {
    return {
        status: 200,
        jsonBody: {
            headers: request.headers,
            context: context
        }
    };
}

app.http('download', {
    route: "download",
    methods: ['GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: download
});

module.exports = download;
```

I just want to see the request headers, because I need them for another endpoint that I'm developing. This is my `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "dataType": "binary",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "download"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, no matter what I do, the headers are always blank no matter what:

```
{
  "headers": {},
  "context": {...}

}
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test",
  "main": "src/**/*.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.1",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "latest"
  }
}
```

I've used ChatGPT and Googled extensively, but have found no answer thus far on why the headers would be completely missing.

I've run `func start` and also `func deploy ...`, and the headers are empty in both environments.

UPDATE: HERE'S the `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

And `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your host.json and local.settings.json data here?

Comment: @DasariKamali done! I added them to the body of the question.

Comment: I was able to get the [output](https://i.imgur.com/rJi0U2b.png) with your code.

Comment: I see that! It seems weird that there are no headers, right?

Comment: I tried another code to get the header in the console, can you check it once?
**Output** : [1](https://i.imgur.com/64IJqOK.png),    [2](https://i.imgur.com/9hqIDdb.png).

Comment: I tried that as well, and retried it just now. I used an anonymous inline function, and I'm still seeing no headers.

The next thing I'm going to try is using an older version of @azure/functions. But that's a tomorrow task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255559/discussion-between-dasari-kamali-and-ryancammer).

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @CaffGeek check out the answer below. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer came from [Pramod Valava from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1386034/why-are-headers-completely-missing-from-a-request?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1331706#newest-answer-comment):

```
const headers = Object.fromEntries(request.headers.entries());

return {
    jsonBody: {
        headers
    }
};
```

Comment: this worked for me, why was it so hard to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to retrieve the request as text and then parse it as JSON with:

```js
const reqText = await request.text();
const reqTextJson = JSON.parse(body);
```

Then you can access the headers with `reqTextJson.headers`